# Peer to peer chat application in php

Tags: php

I am new to PHP, I need some information about how to develop peer to peer chat for the organization.
What are the things I need to do?

Where do I need to store the chatting information?

Could you please give some suggestions on this?

Answer (score 3):

You will store the chatting info in a MySQL database or some other database. Then your page will continually reload the data using ajax. [Here](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/58937-simple-chat-system-using-php-mysql-and-ajax/) is a real simple one.

Comment: General question, general answer. +1

Comment: Thank you for your early responded.But i don't want to interact with the database.could you please help me is there any other process available for peer-peer chatting  application   apart from the data base .

Comment: Guess you could store the chat info in a text file or something but that would be much more complicated.